Weak convergence in $L^2$ equivalence
Problem statement: Denoting by $B_r$ the open ball of $\mathbb{R}^N$ centered at the origin with radius $r$, consider a sequence $f_n \in L^2(B_1)$ which is bounded in the $L^2$ norm. Prove that $f_n$ converges weakly to $0$ in $L^2(B_1)$ if and only if the sequence
$$
F_n:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}, r \mapsto \int_{B_r}f_n
$$
converges uniformly to zero.
My progress: I observed the following:
$f_n \to 0$ weakly in $L^2(B_1)$ $\iff$ $\forall \phi \in L^2(B_1)^*$, we have $\phi(f_n) \to 0$ $\iff$ $\forall g \in L^2(B_1), \int_{B_1}f_ng \to 0$, using the fact that $L^2(B_1)^* = L_2(B_1)$, but cannot proceed any further.
Any hints/solutions would be appreciated.

The statement is false. Take $N=1$ and consider an  odd function $f$  in $L^{2}$.  Let $f_n =f$ for all $n$.  Then $F_n\equiv 0$ for every $n$ but $(f_n)$ does not converge in any sense to $0$  unless $f=0$.
